# SQL Assignment – Airport Database

Tags: sql, database, variable-assignment

**List all states and the number of airports in each state, total and average airport size sorted by size in descending order.**

```
CREATE TABLE Airport(
    AirName     char(3)     NOT NULL,
    City        varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    State       varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Size        int     NULL,
    YearOpened  int     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT AirportPK PRIMARY KEY(AirName));

CREATE TABLE Skill(
    SkillNum    int     NOT NULL,
    SkillName   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    SkillCat    varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SkillPK PRIMARY KEY(SkillNum));


CREATE TABLE Mechanic(
    MechNum     int     NOT NULL,
    MechName    varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    Salary      decimal(9,2)    NULL,
    AirName     char(3)     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT MechanicPK PRIMARY KEY(MechNum),
    CONSTRAINT AirportFK FOREIGN KEY(AirName)
        REFERENCES Airport(AirName)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE Qualification(
    MechNum     Int NOT NULL,
    SkillNum    Int NOT NULL,
    ProfRate    Int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT QualPK PRIMARY KEY(MechNum, SkillNum),
    CONSTRAINT MechanicFK FOREIGN KEY(MechNum)
        REFERENCES Mechanic(MechNum)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT SkillFK FOREIGN KEY(SkillNum)
        REFERENCES Skill(SkillNum)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE NO ACTION);

INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('DFW', 'Dallas', 'Texas', 60, 1950)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('JFK', 'New York', 'New York', 45, 1940)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('LAX', 'Los Angeles', 'California', 55, 1925)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('LGA', 'New York', 'New York', 35, 1930)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('MDW', 'Chicago', 'Illinois', 15, 1925)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('MEM', 'Memphis', 'Tennessee', 40, 1932)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('MIA', 'Miami', 'Florida', 55, 1930)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('MOD', 'Modesto', 'California', 15, 1938)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('MRY', 'Monterey', 'California', 15, 1948)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('ONT', 'Ontario', 'California', 45, 1946)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('ORD', 'Chicago', 'Illinois', 50, 1925)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('PSP', 'Palm Springs', 'California', 18, 1932)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('SAN', 'San Diego', 'California', 40, 1928)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('SFO', 'San Francisco', 'California', 30, 1930)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('SJC', 'San Jose', 'California', 47, 1937)
INSERT INTO Airport VALUES ('SMF', 'Sacramento', 'California', 55, 1940)

INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (1837, 'Engine Replacement', 'Engine')
INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (2244, 'Tire Change', 'Exterior')
INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (2695, 'Fuel System', 'Engine')
INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (2800, 'Cockpit Instruments', 'Instruments')
INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (2854, 'Flight Data Recorder', 'Instruments')
INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (2855, 'Flight Voice Recorder', 'Instruments')
INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (3721, 'Fan Blade Replacement', 'Engine')
INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (4394, 'Air Conditioning', 'Cabin')
INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (6238, 'Fuselage Repair', 'Exterior')
INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (8361, 'Seat Repair', 'Cabin')
INSERT INTO Skill VALUES (9237, 'Glass Repair', 'Exterior')

INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (3817, 'Rose', 71900, 'MOD')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (4187, 'Singh', 52900, 'SFO')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (11299, 'Young', 42900, 'DFW')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (13829, 'Stevens', 68200, 'LAX')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (15289, 'Baker', 42800, 'MOD')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (28392, 'Smith', 65000, 'SFO')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (29246, 'Smith', 50000, 'LAX')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (29517, 'Norton', 47300, 'LAX')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (31387, 'Baker', 61800, 'SJC')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (32781, 'Perez', 52800, 'SFO')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (38110, 'Adams', 63500, 'PSP')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (39481, 'Vincent', 52800, 'SJC')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (41287, 'Kirby', 52000, 'ONT')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (42728, 'Johnson', 52900, 'ONT')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (44100, 'Walters', 62900, 'MIA')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (49128, 'Taylor', 58300, 'PSP')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (52822, 'Caldwell', 51500, 'MRY')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (62928, 'Martin', 47300, 'ORD')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (62999, 'Lorimer', 42900, 'SMF')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (67183, 'Schwartz', 62700, 'JFK')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (71919, 'Gonzalez', 62900, 'SAN')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (77289, 'Edwards', 49500, 'MEM')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (83710, 'Williams', 67000, 'SMF')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (84728, 'Jackson', 45000, 'SAN')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (90274, 'Chen', 52000, 'LGA')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (91838, 'Vega', 47200, 'MRY')
INSERT INTO Mechanic VALUES (92729, 'Martin', 58200, 'LAX')

INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(3817, 1837, 6)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(3817, 3721, 7)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(3817, 4394, 7)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(15289, 2854, 2)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(15289, 3721, 2)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(28392, 2855, 4)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(29246, 3721, 3)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(29517, 2695, 5)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(31387, 3721, 4)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(32781, 3721, 6)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(38110, 3721, 4)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(39481, 3721, 2)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(39481, 9237, 4)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(41287, 2800, 5)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(42728, 2855, 3)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(42728, 8361, 5)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(44100, 3721, 4)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(44100, 9237, 3)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(52822, 1837, 3)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(62928, 3721, 4)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(62999, 2244, 2)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(67183, 3721, 4)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(77289, 3721, 5)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(90274, 6238, 5)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(91838, 3721, 4)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(92729, 2800, 6)
INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES(92729, 3721, 5)
```

Comment: We need context to know what kind of answer you expect. Can you make your own attempt for us to use as a starting point? You're also much more likely to get a good answer here if you spend some time investigating the formatting options, to edit the question and make this code more readable.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problem are you facing? This isn't a free write-my-code or do-my-research service. We will help you with a task you have tried to solve yourself, where you have encountered a specific issue. We're usually less willing to help if you don't appear to have made any effort yourself before asking (unless perhaps it's something quite trivial). If you _have_ made some effort, then please demonstrate it here e.g. by providing some code you tried, and/or detailing the research you've done, the ideas you found, and why they aren't helpful to you in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Besides, if we just do your homework for you, you won't learn anything useful. If you want to get good at coding, you'll need to put some thought into it. If you try something and get stuck, that's where we can maybe help to clarify things.

Comment: can I have help with this question I am not sure about the answer SELECT State , AirName
SUM(AirName) AS NumberOfAirports
from 
Airport
Order By Size DESC

Comment: Well, does it produce the result you wanted, or not? Work out (by hand if necessary) what you think the correct result should be and then build a query which produces it. Does you current query produce the expected result or not? If not, and if you need help, then please update the question with the query, the expected results and the actual results. Then we understand better what you're doing. Thanks

Comment: P.S. Why did you include the skill, mechanic and qualification tables to clutter up your question? They appear to be entirely irrelevant to the exercise. It makes your question much harder to read and appear more complicated than it really is. In future please ensure you discern what is likely to be relevant to your issue and only include that in your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT State, COUNT(AirName) NO_OF_AIRPORTS, SUM(Size) TOTAL_SIZE, AVG(Size) AVERAGE_SIZE
FROM Airport
GROUP BY State
ORDER BY TOTAL_SIZE DESC;
```

Comment: thanks, Ankit Bajpai for helping me with my homework, the answer was correct

Comment: You are always welcome.